# Returning False VS echoing out an error

Tags: php, return-type

I'm trying to understand the main difference between returning false from a statement as oppose to echoing out an error promoting the user to correct their submission.

Lets take the following function that is used to get the Google Currency Convert API URL and parse in another 3 parameters, `$amount, $from, $to`.  I use `explode` to obtain the numeric values returned within `""` by the API.

```
function currency_convert($googleCurrencyApi, $amount, $from, $to) {

    $result = file_get_contents($googleCurrencyApi . $amount . $from . '=?' . $to);
    $expl = explode('"', $result);

    if ($expl[1] == '' || $expl[3] == '') {
        return false;
    } else {
        return array(
            $expl[1],
            $expl[3]
        );
    }
}
```

What is the advantage of returning false if the statement is true compared to echoing out a  a constructive message?  I see return false regularly used on many forums etc.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because you'd be mixing your logic and display code. Use logic to determine what to send to the user. Using your example, if it's validated and okay, do you print out that it's fine? No, you continue processing. If it doesn't validate, you cannot process, so you say that you cannot continue.

Comment: Excellent question. Though I've stopped doing both a long time ago.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Neither, we're in 2012, throw an Exception and handle it in any way you want.

```
function currency_convert($googleCurrencyApi, $amount, $from, $to) {

    $result = file_get_contents($googleCurrencyApi . $amount . $from . '=?' . $to);
    $expl = explode('"', $result);

    if ($expl[1] == '' || $expl[3] == '') {
        throw new Exception('An error has occured. Describe the error here');
    }
    return array(
        $expl[1],
        $expl[3]
    );
}
```

Than, when you call the function:

```
try { currency_convert($googleApi, $amount, $from, $to) }
catch (Exception $e) { /* Do whatever you want with $e */ }
```

**[Read about Exceptions and the try, catch block here](http://il.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php)**

#### Advantages

- If unhandled, will halt the script, quickly pinpointing where the problem is.
- If handled, it can easily by treated as if a `return false` happened.
- Exception halts the function, meaning the return statement will never arrive.
- An Exception can display a constructive message to the user, and it can be helpful for developers to see what the error was.
- Exceptions are Objects whose Classes can be **extended**, so you can effectively create **multiple types of errors and exceptions** such as but not limited to: `IllegalArgumentException`, `MathException`, `FileReadException`, `ReallyAwesomeException`, and then handle each differently

  ```
  try { /* Code Here */ }
  catch (IllegalArgumentException $e) { echo 'Illegal Argument!'; }
  catch (Exception $e) { echo 'General Error! '. $e->getMessage(); }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

There's no advantage of one over the other, it all depends on how you structure your code. You can  return false to a client side method that displays the error.

It's all about what you do with the returned value. If false, display "failed" else "success".

Answer (score 1):

Why? Because:

1. Reusing codes can change it easier and they can change what to do.
2. You can do & validate easier, in one step.
3. Echoing an error will not be constructive on the code side, only on user side. Returning false is good on both.

Answer (score 1):

Functions/methods should only output anything if that's already their purpose.  To give an example:

Bad:

```
function showSomething($something) {
    $something = doSomething($something);
    echo $something;
}

function doSomething($something) {
    if (empty($something)) {
        echo 'ERROR!';
    }

    return $something;
}
```

Good:

```
function showSomething($something) {
    $something = doSomething($something);
    if ($something === FALSE) {
        echo 'ERROR!';
    } else {
        echo $something;
    }
}

function doSomething($something) {
    if (empty($something)) {
        return FALSE;
    }

    return $something;
}
```